# How to rerender parent component after receiving child's ref with useRef hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm banging my head trying to work around one annoying problem:

I have a parent component and a child one. The child has absolute positioning and dynamic height. I need to calculate the parent's margin depending on the child's height. I tried to do something like

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  return (
     <Child saveRef={ref} />
);

const Child = ({saveRef}) => (<div ref={saveRef}> </div>);
```

But the problem is that Parent component doesn't rerender when Ref is fulfilled. 
How can I rerender Parent component after Ref is received?

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write an effect in parent that run on intial mount. This effect will run after the ref is initialized and child in rendered. After this maintain a state in parent which is the margin that you need to calculate and once you calculate the margin update the state

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  const [margin, updateMargin] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
     // calculate margin. Let call it margin
     updateMargin(margin);
  }, []);

  return (
     <Child saveRef={ref} />
);

const Child = ({saveRef}) => (<div ref={saveRef}> </div>);
```

**EDIT:** In order to update on window resize, you need to add an event listener on window resize and recalculate height

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  const [margin, updateMargin] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
     () => {
         window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
     }
  }, []);

  const handleResize = () => {
       // use ref, calcualte margin and update
  }
  return (
     <Child saveRef={ref} />
);
```

Comment: Since the effect involves DOM, this could possibly be a case for `useLayoutEffect`.

Comment: Came to the same solution as @estus suggested. But now I struggle with different problem) On window resize I need recalculate height again

Comment: @MikeErmolaev Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as prop to the child from parent, and call that function when you need to re-render the parent. Changing a state would trigger a render. So in the function you can just Change a state.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
 state = {ref : null}

 handleRef = ref => {
  this.setState({ ref });
  // your add you method for changing margin
 }

 render(){
   return <Child ref={this.state.ref} handleRefChange={this.handleRef} />
 }
}
```

Store the ref in Parent component and call the handleRefChange from Child component to update it.